# How do i compare between these different outputs and see if they are equal

Tags: c++

So I'm supposed to prime-factorize an n number and compare between its prime factors.
IF they are equal then I print "YES" if not, then "NO".
I wrote the code to print the prime factors, but I can't do the comparison.
Here's the code:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    while(n%2==0)
    {
        cout << 2 << endl;
        n/=2;
    }
    for(int i=3;i<sqrt(n);i+=2)
    {
        while(n%i==0)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
            n/=i;
        }
    }
    if(n>2)
    {
        cout << n << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One simple approach you could use; put the prime factors for each number into individual `std::vector`s. Then `std::sort` both vectors. Then compare the vectors for equality.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;` <-- Please don't *ever* do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply! 
I don't really know how to use vectors so I made it like this, and it worked out.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,x,y,z,c;
    cin >> n;
    z=n;
    c=z;
    if(n==1)
    {
        cout << "NO";
        return 0;
    }
    while(n%2==0)
    {
        n/=2;
    }
    if(n==1 && n!=z)
    {
        cout << "YES";
        return 0;
    }
     else if (n!=1 && n!=z)
    {
        cout << "NO";
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i=3;i<z+1;i+=2)

    {

        while(z%i==0)
        {
            z/=i;
        }
        if(c%i==0){
      if(z==1)
      {
          cout << "YES";
          break;
      }
      else if (z!=1)
      {
          cout << "NO";
          break;
      }
        }
        else if (c%i!=0)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }


}
```